# How can I make a writable ManyToManyField with a Through Model in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, many-to-many

I have a Product class that has "source products"; I use a many-to-many field with a through model to represent it (the database tables already exist, and that's the only way I found to configure the models):

```
class Product(models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    product_name = models.TextField()
    source_products = models.ManyToManyField('self', symmetrical=False, related_name='derived_products', through='Link', through_fields=('product', 'source'),)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'product'
        managed = False

class Link(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey('Product', models.CASCADE, db_column='uuid', related_name='source_links')
    source = models.ForeignKey('Product', models.CASCADE, db_column='source_uuid', related_name='+')
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'link'
        unique_together = (('product', 'source'),)
        managed = False
```

My serializer is dead simple:

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('uuid', 'product_name', 'source_products', )
```

A GET request returns:

```
{
    "product_name": "dummy.fra",
    "source_products": [
        "17b021e7-3d6b-4d29-a80b-895d62710080"
    ],
    "uuid": "48c5a344-877e-4e3f-9a4b-2daa136b68fe"
}
```

The since [ManyToManyFields with a Through Model are read-only](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#manytomanyfields-with-a-through-model), how do I go about to create a product  including the link between products? I'd like to send a POST request that follows the same format as the GET response (i.e., a `source_products` field that lists UUIDs of existing products).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` but you have to write custom create method.

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    source_products = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, queryset=Products.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('uuid', 'product_name', 'source_products', )

    def create(self, validated_data):
        source_products = validated_data.pop('source_products', [])
        product = Product.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for source in source_products:
            product.source_products.add(source)
        return product
```

Your data will be like this

```
{
    "product_name": "dummy.fra",
    "source_products": [
        "17b021e7-3d6b-4d29-a80b-895d62710080"
    ],
    "uuid": "48c5a344-877e-4e3f-9a4b-2daa136b68fe"
}
```

Comment: Nice! But PrimaryKeyRelatedField needs a `queryset` defined. And `validated_data` contains the source products as objects, so there is no need to retrieve `product_obj`. Should I do the edits?

Answer (score 0):

The serializer has to override `create()` and access the unvalidated GET parameters (`self.context['request'].data`) directly:

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def create(self, validated_data):
        # extract sources data
        unvalidated_data = self.context['request'].data
        sources_data = unvalidated_data.get('source_products', [])
        # save objects
        instance = Product.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for uuid in sources_data:
            source = Product.objects.get(pk=uuid)
            instance.source_links.create(source=source)
        return instance

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('uuid', 'product_name', 'source_products', )
```