# Error writing to many to many field django rest framework api

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

This seems to be my solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/48636446/7989638 (for "How can I make a writable ManyToManyField with a Through Model in Django Rest Framework?
") but I am getting this error :

{"images":["Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received unicode."]}

their solution works in the create method of the serializer but i debugged and checked that it never reaches that method; returns error beforehand.

Could you please help me fix this.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show your models,serializers and the POST payload?

Comment: Using write only fields and then overriding create method solved my problem. Thank you @JPG